# Amazon API product unavailable (but available on Amazon website)

Tags: php, amazon-product-api

I'm having an issue with many of the products pulled from Amazon Product API's Search and Lookup functions. The details for the product are showing as unavailable and I cannot do the cartAdd function on them. It says on Amazon's documentation that I should check for OfferListingId to make sure the product is really available. The products also show 0 offers

```
[Offers] => stdClass Object ( [TotalOffers] => 0 [TotalOfferPages] => 0 [MoreOffersUrl] => 0 )
```

When you click on the Amazon URL for the product, it shows as available on Amazon! I'm trying to either filter out products that the user is unable to add to cart (with me using CartAdd function), or find a way to be able to use the CartAdd function to add them. The products that need to be added to cart often are ones that have options such as size. Has anyone dealt with this problem before. Here is an example of a product that does this (I have the output on the page or see below):

http://acmebillingco.com/amazonStoreStage/details.php?id=B010L5B3HW

```
stdClass Object ( [ASIN] => B010L5B3HW [ParentASIN] => B010L5B3HW [DetailPageURL] => http://www.amazon.com/Ularmo-Popular-Gothic-Temptation-Earring/dp/B010L5B3HW%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAJEBEDTZ6GV7BOLTQ%26tag%3Dxgfcom-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3DB010L5B3HW [ItemLinks] => stdClass Object ( [ItemLink] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [Description] => Technical Details [URL] => http://www.amazon.com/Ularmo-Popular-Gothic-Temptation-Earring/dp/tech-data/B010L5B3HW%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAJEBEDTZ6GV7BOLTQ%26tag%3Dxgfcom-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3DB010L5B3HW ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [Description] => Add To Baby Registry [URL] => http://www.amazon.com/gp/registry/baby/add-item.html%3Fasin.0%3DB010L5B3HW%26SubscriptionId%3DAKIAJEBEDTZ6GV7BOLTQ%26tag%3Dxgfcom-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3DB010L5B3HW ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [Description] => Add To Wedding Registry [URL] => http://www.amazon.com/gp/registry/wedding/add-item.html%3Fasin.0%3DB010L5B3HW%26SubscriptionId%3DAKIAJEBEDTZ6GV7BOLTQ%26tag%3Dxgfcom-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3DB010L5B3HW ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [Description] => Add To Wishlist [URL] => http://www.amazon.com/gp/registry/wishlist/add-item.html%3Fasin.0%3DB010L5B3HW%26SubscriptionId%3DAKIAJEBEDTZ6GV7BOLTQ%26tag%3Dxgfcom-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3DB010L5B3HW ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [Description] => Tell A Friend [URL] => http://www.amazon.com/gp/pdp/taf/B010L5B3HW%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAJEBEDTZ6GV7BOLTQ%26tag%3Dxgfcom-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3DB010L5B3HW ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [Description] => All Customer Reviews [URL] => http://www.amazon.com/review/product/B010L5B3HW%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAJEBEDTZ6GV7BOLTQ%26tag%3Dxgfcom-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3DB010L5B3HW ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [Description] => All Offers [URL] => http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B010L5B3HW%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAJEBEDTZ6GV7BOLTQ%26tag%3Dxgfcom-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3DB010L5B3HW ) ) ) [SmallImage] => stdClass Object ( [URL] => http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51nTjejZ4rL._SL75_.jpg [Height] => 75 [Width] => 75 ) [MediumImage] => stdClass Object ( [URL] => http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51nTjejZ4rL._SL160_.jpg [Height] => 160 [Width] => 160 ) [LargeImage] => stdClass Object ( [URL] => http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51nTjejZ4rL.jpg [Height] => 500 [Width] => 500 ) [ImageSets] => stdClass Object ( [ImageSet] => stdClass Object ( [@attributes] => stdClass Object ( [Category] => primary ) [SwatchImage] => stdClass Object ( [URL] => http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51nTjejZ4rL._SL30_.jpg [Height] => 30 [Width] => 30 ) [SmallImage] => stdClass Object ( [URL] => http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51nTjejZ4rL._SL75_.jpg [Height] => 75 [Width] => 75 ) [ThumbnailImage] => stdClass Object ( [URL] => http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51nTjejZ4rL._SL75_.jpg [Height] => 75 [Width] => 75 ) [TinyImage] => stdClass Object ( [URL] => http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51nTjejZ4rL._SL110_.jpg [Height] => 110 [Width] => 110 ) [MediumImage] => stdClass Object ( [URL] => http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51nTjejZ4rL._SL160_.jpg [Height] => 160 [Width] => 160 ) [LargeImage] => stdClass Object ( [URL] => http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51nTjejZ4rL.jpg [Height] => 500 [Width] => 500 ) ) ) [ItemAttributes] => stdClass Object ( [Binding] => Misc. [Brand] => Ularmo® [Department] => womens [Feature] => Array ( [0] => Material: Alloy, Quantity: 1PC [1] => Catch this beautiful accessories for you [2] => Wonderful gift for you and your friends [3] => Match with suitable apparel for different occasion [4] => Special design and unique structure, a popular item ) [IsAutographed] => 0 [IsMemorabilia] => 0 [Label] => Ularmo [ListPrice] => stdClass Object ( [Amount] => 330 [CurrencyCode] => USD [FormattedPrice] => $3.30 ) [Manufacturer] => Ularmo [MPN] => Ularmo-015 [NumberOfItems] => 1 [PackageQuantity] => 1 [PartNumber] => Ularmo-015 [ProductGroup] => Sports [ProductTypeName] => SPORTING_GOODS [Publisher] => Ularmo [Studio] => Ularmo [Title] => Ularmo Popular Gothic Punk Temptation Ear Cuff Wrap Clip Cool Earring ) [OfferSummary] => stdClass Object ( [TotalNew] => 0 [TotalUsed] => 0 [TotalCollectible] => 0 [TotalRefurbished] => 0 ) [Offers] => stdClass Object ( [TotalOffers] => 0 [TotalOfferPages] => 0 [MoreOffersUrl] => 0 ) [CustomerReviews] => stdClass Object ( [IFrameURL] => http://www.amazon.com/reviews/iframe?akid=AKIAJEBEDTZ6GV7BOLTQ&alinkCode=xm2&asin=B010L5B3HW&atag=xgfcom-20&exp=2016-04-28T20%3A55%3A33Z&v=2&sig=kgke5B0b4kklDKiJmIG59pWuaNHnHEEVG6SAtKOKL9k%3D [HasReviews] => true ) [EditorialReviews] => stdClass Object ( [EditorialReview] => stdClass Object ( [Source] => Product Description [Content] => Package Include: 
1X Earring(Without retail package) [IsLinkSuppressed] => 0 ) ) )
```

Comment: basically you cannot buy this product, because it is "parent" product, it has several children, each of them represents particular color/size and which can be bought

Comment: Maybe off topic but not worth down voting.